# who i can run shell (.sh) scripts in Centos X64 and read output?

Tags: java, linux, shell, sh, centos7

I'm using Intellij IDEA and i'm trying to run a shell script with arguments, and read the result of the execution.
this **script** is on my java SRC packge,
 *myScript.sh run a compiled c program*

```
 String[] cmd = { "/bin/bash", "-c", "myScript" };
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Comment: Is there an error?

Comment: no Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: @notyou **is there any way** to run a program using shell.sh in linux.
i have a root permissions and this program is on my package with my _main class_ and also this program run normally whene i do call from the terminal !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i resolved this by making a copy of **myScript.sh in /ect/bin.**
so this make my script as an environment path and give me the ability to read all the out put or add supplement *arguments*.
no changes has been made

> on my Java code

.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ProcessBuilder`:

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder(cmd).start();
```

Then `process.getInputStream()` gives you access to the process standard output (stdout) which you can read as usual; `process.getErrorStream()` allows to read standard error (stderr).

Also you can do `process.waitFor()` to wait for the project to finish.

Note that to read anything from the stdout of a process you need to wait for the process to finish (or read it in a loop) and not just finish your main program.

Comment: sorry but i tried this!! no thing happend.
if you get any solution please share how to resolve this!